# Tool helping with estimations

Tags: project-management, tools, estimation

I am looking for a tool supporting me with estimations.

What I would like to do is to specify a higher level task and break it into several smaller tasks. When a task is small enough, I could assign the time it takes to finish it. The sum of these quantifiers should show up in the parent tasks.

One could use Project for this, but IMHO this is some kind of overkill ...

Also nice would be if you could do this like mindmapping so that a parant node sums up all of its childs estimations.

Is something like this out there?

Comment: **[resource requests are not quite welcome at Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-questions/info "see respective meta tag and questions")**. As far as I understand, one would rather present an **underlying problem** instead - a problem that was intended to be solved with particular resource requested

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try AbstractSpoon's [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.com/). It has also been packaged as a [portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/todolist_portable) application.

You can type the estimate in the “Time Est.” field (and choose a unit). They will add up to the parent task.

[image: Screenshot]